# Minecraft Forge Modding (1.16.2) - my en_us.json file doesn't work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I created an item called: "sapphire" my textures work, item does what it should but it doesn't display the name I want, my `en_us.json` file looks like this:

```
"item.mymodid.sapphire": "Sapphire"
```

in game it says: `item.mymodid.sapphire`

but this is not just items my creative tab doesn't work too, in `.json` file
I have this :

```
"itemGroup.gems":"Gem Items"
```

in game it says: `itemGroup.gems`

Please help I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Check the `.json` file with https://jsonlint.com/ to make sure it's formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

Lang files is really json files.
True content will be:

```json
{
    "item.mymodid.sapphire": "Sapphire"
}
```

If you using Intellij Idea, try to add to the begin of your build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = true
    }
}
```

And do [image: Refresh Gradle]`Refresh Gradle`

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are putting the class name to the wrong spot. Try flipping their places like this `"Gem Items":"itemGroup.gems"`